# Pass function parameter to Pig

Tags: function, parameters, apache-pig

Here is my problem with Apache Pig, I run Pig script in a Python script. There is a field called priority in Pig, whose value is either a random number, or just null. Each record of input should have a different random number. Python code would determine between random number and null before call Pig script.

Scenario one:
pig -param param1="" -f my_pig_script.pig

scenario two(just guess):
pig -function param1=random() -f my_pig_script.pig

How two write right Pig script under scenario two?

Thanks

Comment: should python code choose between random number and null for every row? or it decides only once and it applies to all the rows?

Comment: It decides only once and applies to all the rows. Thanks for your patience, Gaurav!

Comment: updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is for sure - you do not need to (actually should not) pass random() as param, as it would pass ONLY 1 RANDOM NUMBER as param, which you do not want.
The question is how to convey your PIG script to use null or random. Go ahead and pass null or non-null value to param1, pass non-null when you want pig script to use random instead of null.

Inside PIG script, you can use ternary operator as below:

```
A = FOREACH B GENERATE param1 IS NULL ? NULL : RANDOM();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could I use: pig -param param1="" -param param2=Random() -f myScript.pig ?  Does -f mean the second parameter is a function?  Thanks!

Comment: no, -f parameter specifies the pig script file. I'm wondering why are you not executing Random() function in python and passing the randorm value as param?

Comment: ok, actually, I need to pass a Pig function. The python program will determine which one should be used from null or Random(). I want to realize it in one pig script. If not, maybe two different pig scripts would be a better idea.

Comment: well, it's a good idea to generate the random number in python!

Comment: I need a different random number for each record. If my input is too big, python won't help.

Comment: you can generate the random number in pig script as well.

Comment: sorry about my description of this problem. Python code needs to determine null or random() before running the pig script. They are the value of filed: priority.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the question and give example if possible?